# Why hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin compiles sources twice?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

Recently I start to use `hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin` and noticed that Maven executes *compile* phase twice. After some research I found that it's happening because [`MavenEnhancePlugin`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/tooling/hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/hibernate/orm/tooling/maven/MavenEnhancePlugin.java#L52) (it's a plugin implementation) is annotated with [`@Execute`](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugins/annotations/Execute.html).

So what is the reason to execute phase twice? Or, maybe it's just a bug?

Comment: Looks like a small bug yes. It doesn't have any impact because the second run will do nothing anyway. It would be useful to have `@Execute` if it were intended to be ran on the command-line, but judging from [the docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/topical/html/bytecode/BytecodeEnhancement.html#_maven_plugin), it is meant to be used in the POM as part of the default lifecycle. So there is no need to fork it.

Comment: @Tunaki, the bad thing about that is that is actually forces recompilation. I have almost 200 classes in project, and impact is quite noticeable.

Comment: Hmm it shouldn't do that, I think. Are you using latest Maven version? With 3.3.9 I don't see any recompilation.

Comment: @Tunaki, the problem was in package-info files. They never produce .class files, and maven thought that they changed. Anyway, thanks for your time)